# box2d: Getting a SIGABRT on ResetMassData, b2Assert(m_I > 0.0f) - Center inertia, centre of mass

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to make a bucket body that responds when another specific body touches the inside floor of the basket, for example, an apple...

The problem I'm having now, is that after splitting the basket in to 3 shapes, it now crashes on construction of the body with: `Assertion failed: (m_I > 0.0f), function ResetMassData, file /Users/damianwilliams/Documents/XCode Projects/Will Replace Old/Kitty Katch/Kitty Katch/libs/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp, line 319.`

But this doesn't happen if i declare the body as a static body...

Neither does it happen if I only have one (either) of the sides and the bottom to be added to the body!

Here is all the code for constructing it, I'm guessing its a simple fix, but I can't see it :(

```
@implementation HelloWorldLayer
{
    CCSprite *_theBag;
    b2Body *_basketBody;
    b2Fixture *_basketLeftBodyFix;
    b2Fixture *_basketRightBodyFix;
    b2Fixture *_basketBottomFixture;
}

-(id) init { if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(50, 180, 220, 255)]) )
{
    // Create the Basket body--------------------------
    _theBag = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Basket.png"];
    _theBag.opacity = 30;
    _theBag.scale = 0.5;
    [self addChild:_theBag z:35];

    b2BodyDef theBasketBodyDef;
    theBasketBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
    theBasketBodyDef.position.Set(220/PTM_RATIO, 150/PTM_RATIO);
    theBasketBodyDef.userData = (__bridge void*)_theBag;
    theBasketBodyDef.angularDamping = 25.0;
    _basketBody = _world->CreateBody(&theBasketBodyDef);

    // Create basket shape
    int scalledPTMRatio = PTM_RATIO * (10 / (_theBag.scale * 10)); // Needed if the sprite image is scalled...
    int numLeftVerts = 5;
    b2Vec2 leftVerts[] = {
        b2Vec2(-98.4f / scalledPTMRatio, 51.2f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-65.6f / scalledPTMRatio, 38.6f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-59.6f / scalledPTMRatio, -73.0f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-71.0f / scalledPTMRatio, -68.8f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-97.8f / scalledPTMRatio, 51.1f / scalledPTMRatio)
    };

    b2PolygonShape basketLeftShape;
    basketLeftShape.Set(leftVerts, numLeftVerts);

     int numRightVerts = 5;
     b2Vec2 rightVerts[] = {
        b2Vec2(98.2f / scalledPTMRatio, 43.7f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(56.6f / scalledPTMRatio, 36.6f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(45.9f / scalledPTMRatio, -80.0f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(53.8f / scalledPTMRatio, -78.4f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(98.5f / scalledPTMRatio, 41.2f / scalledPTMRatio)
    };

    b2PolygonShape basketRightShape;
    basketRightShape.Set(rightVerts, numRightVerts);

    // Create shape def and add to body
    b2FixtureDef theBasketLeftShapeDef;
     theBasketLeftShapeDef.shape = &basketLeftShape;
     theBasketLeftShapeDef.density = 5.0f;
    theBasketLeftShapeDef.friction = 0.9f;
    theBasketLeftShapeDef.restitution = 0.2f;
    _basketLeftBodyFix = _basketBody->CreateFixture(&theBasketLeftShapeDef);

    b2FixtureDef theBasketRightShapeDef;
    theBasketRightShapeDef.shape = &basketRightShape;
    theBasketRightShapeDef.density = 5.0f;
    theBasketRightShapeDef.friction = 0.9f;
    theBasketRightShapeDef.restitution = 0.2f;
    _basketRightBodyFix = _basketBody->CreateFixture(&theBasketRightShapeDef);

    // Create the bottom of the basket
    b2PolygonShape basketBottomShape;
    basketBottomShape.SetAsBox(0.7, 0.1, b2Vec2(-0.1, -1), 0.0);

    b2FixtureDef basketBottomShapeDef;
    basketBottomShapeDef.shape = &basketBottomShape;
    basketBottomShapeDef.density = 10.0f;
    basketBottomShapeDef.friction = 1.0f;
    basketBottomShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;
    MyUserData *thebasketBottomUserData = (MyUserData*)malloc(sizeof(MyUserData));
    thebasketBottomUserData->myTag = 4;
    basketBottomShapeDef.userData = thebasketBottomUserData;
    _basketBottomFixture = _basketBody ->CreateFixture(&basketBottomShapeDef);
}
```

This is where the crash occurs in the `b2Body.cpp` file...

```
if (m_I > 0.0f && (m_flags & e_fixedRotationFlag) == 0)
{
    // Center the inertia about the center of mass.
    m_I -= m_mass * b2Dot(localCenter, localCenter);
    b2Assert(m_I > 0.0f);
    m_invI = 1.0f / m_I;
}
```

---

Back trace..

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2ba286, 0x02ae8952 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x02ae8952 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
frame #1: 0x02aac167 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
frame #2: 0x0281b9c9 libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 127
frame #3: 0x027e653b libsystem_sim_c.dylib`__assert_rtn + 284
* frame #4: 0x001020d8 Kitty Katch`b2Body::ResetMassData(this=0x0f2cd1e0) + 744 at b2Body.cpp:319
frame #5: 0x00101d30 Kitty Katch`b2Body::SetType(this=0x0f2cd1e0, type=b2_dynamicBody) + 208 at b2Body.cpp:128
frame #6: 0x000b8cdc Kitty Katch`-[HelloWorldLayer startGame](self=0x0b7958c0, _cmd=0x0a910d1f) + 60 at HelloWorldLayer.mm:340
frame #7: 0x000ba41d Kitty Katch`-[HelloWorldLayer startGameStub:](self=0x0b7958c0, _cmd=0x0013862f, sender=0x0c782e70) + 77 at HelloWorldLayer.mm:471
frame #8: 0x0240e82b libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
frame #9: 0x0006d367 Kitty Katch`__49-[CCMenuItemLabel initWithLabel:target:selector:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>, sender=0x0c782e70) + 71 at CCMenuItem.m:193
frame #10: 0x0006cc5c Kitty Katch`-[CCMenuItem activate](self=0x0c782e70, _cmd=0x00c32eb8) + 108 at CCMenuItem.m:135
frame #11: 0x0006d890 Kitty Katch`-[CCMenuItemLabel activate](self=0x0c782e70, _cmd=0x00c32eb8) + 160 at CCMenuItem.m:246
frame #12: 0x001187e9 Kitty Katch`-[CCMenu ccTouchEnded:withEvent:](self=0x0c7844f0, _cmd=0x0012f7fa, touch=0x0b791aa0, event=0x0b685d60) + 297 at CCMenu.m:228
frame #13: 0x0240e880 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
frame #14: 0x001261ae Kitty Katch`-[CCTouchDispatcher touches:withEvent:withTouchType:](self=0x0c39e2e0, _cmd=0x0013b5e2, touches=0x0c3b9130, event=0x0b685d60, idx=2) + 1534 at CCTouchDispatcher.m:292
frame #15: 0x00126d83 Kitty Katch`-[CCTouchDispatcher touchesEnded:withEvent:](self=0x0c39e2e0, _cmd=0x00c0e017, touches=0x0c3b9130, event=0x0b685d60) + 115 at CCTouchDispatcher.m:366
frame #16: 0x000b44be Kitty Katch`-[CCGLView touchesEnded:withEvent:](self=0x0c397440, _cmd=0x00c0e017, touches=0x0c3b9130, event=0x0b685d60) + 110 at CCGLView.m:349
frame #17: 0x0047dddd UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
frame #18: 0x0047e9d1 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
frame #19: 0x004505f2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
frame #20: 0x0043a353 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
frame #21: 0x0344e77f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
frame #22: 0x0344e10b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
frame #23: 0x0346b1ae CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 910
frame #24: 0x0346a9d3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
frame #25: 0x0346a7eb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #26: 0x032375ee GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #27: 0x0323742b GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #28: 0x0043cf9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
frame #29: 0x00126f06 Kitty Katch`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffed54) + 134 at main.m:14
frame #30: 0x00002e85 Kitty Katch`start + 53
```

---

I've also looked at overlapping points following another user's advice. there were bad points, however fixing them didn't help the bug. I completely redid the objects in question, and the bug remains...

```
int scalledPTMRatio = PTM_RATIO ; //scalled...
int numLeftVerts = 6;
b2Vec2 leftVerts[] = {
    b2Vec2(-18.2f / scalledPTMRatio, -17.1f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(-20.6f / scalledPTMRatio, -31.0f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(-29.0f / scalledPTMRatio, -27.7f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(-38.6f / scalledPTMRatio, 20.3f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(-24.3f / scalledPTMRatio, 16.1f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(-21.2f / scalledPTMRatio, -13.2f / scalledPTMRatio)
};

b2PolygonShape basketLeftShape;
basketLeftShape.Set(leftVerts, numLeftVerts);

int numRightVerts = 6;
b2Vec2 rightVerts[] = {
    b2Vec2(14.6f / scalledPTMRatio, -13.0f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(11.6f / scalledPTMRatio, -32.9f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(21.8f / scalledPTMRatio, -31.3f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(39.2f / scalledPTMRatio, 17.1f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(20.4f / scalledPTMRatio, 14.4f / scalledPTMRatio),
    b2Vec2(17.7f / scalledPTMRatio, -10.5f / scalledPTMRatio)
};
```

I'm not sure what I'm looking for or why I'm getting the error. Theres nothing interesting in the debug window except for above quoted error, I'm hoping someone can take my code above, see the problem on their end, and then provide instructions on how to diagnose the issue and ultimately help me fix it.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused by the polygon being self-intersecting.

[image]

iirc you can also hit this assert when the polygon is wound clockwise, or has zero area (due to all points being colinear). There is also another similar assertion somewhere that can hit when these all these things are correct but the polygon is simply too small.

Comment: Waw.... if this is correct, hat off to you sir!! Because while testing, I'm finding that some objects are falling trough the poly. What software is this screen shot from, thanks...!

Comment: I'm not sure this is it, but really hoped it was.... I completely redid the points from scratch, keeping the loin points away from any activity. but it was not helping... Is it possible that the objects are too small?

Comment: The points are also wound clockwise. Remove the last point (since it's almost on top of the first one and is kinda redundant) and reverse the order.

Comment: This was the solution! - Firstly i learned that the last line is automatically inserted by box... your comment about my last point being redundant was the hint there. But theres one thing I'm stuck on... Why did reversing the points have the effect of braking it?

Comment: Also what is the software that you used to check the points... that look like it might come in handy

Comment: Points for polygons in Box2D should be given in counter-clockwise order and form a convex, non-self-intersecting polygon with no more than 8 vertices. When the points are wound clockwise, the area calculation becomes negative. I'd hate to point you to an external site again, but the Box2D manual lays out all the details and is well worth a read: http://www.box2d.org/manual.html :) The software is RUBE Box2D editor.

Comment: I appreciate your tong-in-cheek humour, i will defo RTFM, and I guess at first I assumed you were simply flogging/name dropping your site. But I defiantly appreciate your help here, because I've wasted so many hours trying to figure this out. P.S. I have minor questions that wouldn't really warrant a question here. Is there a way you & I can chat? a PM system? or maybe outside of StackOverflow if necessary. I get the feeling that you are able to quick fire these off for me...

Comment: Best way to chat for me is gmail chat, iforce2d@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54761/discussion-between-iforce2d-and-monkey-puzzle).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a raw "crash", it is an assertion failure.

The Assert is failing, so let's look at it.

At runtime, `m_I > 0.0f` is `false`, so `m_I <= 0.0f` is `true`.
Because `m_I > 0.0f` if true (its a condition of the `if`), we deduct that `m_mass * b2Dot(localCenter, localCenter) <= 0.0f`

So either `m_mass <= 0.0f` or `b2Dot(localCenter, localCenter) <= 0.0f`. A quick look with your debugger at the generated core will show you their values: either one of them should not be negative and is, either your assertion is wrong.

Comment: The debug window is pretty empty... Its got the standard stuff, and the quoted one in my question... Not sure what I'm looking for or why I'm getting the error. I'm hoping someone can take my code above, see the problem on their end, and then provide instructions on how to diagnose the issue and ultimately fix it.

Comment: The debug window and the console window are really not the same thing : the debugger can provide you with variables values before the assert failure (looking at the backtrace).

Comment: yes i believe what I'm looking at is the debug window, along side the variables window? says "All Output"... says (lldb)? where i can type bt for backtrace? - Will add backtrace to question in a moment... If this isn't right, can you say how to get it please? thanks